# I can't get my photos to do anything in css

Tags: html

```
<div id="travel_photos">
  <img style="display: inline; margin: 0 10px; title="branson" src="branson.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="75"/>
  <img style="display: inline; margin: 0 10px; title="cancun" src="cancun.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="75"/>
  <img style="display: inline; margin: 0 10px; title="denver" src="denver.png" alt="" width="150" height="75"/>
  <img style="display: inline; margin: 0 10px; title="destin" src="destin.png" alt="" width="150" height="75"/>
  <img style="display: inline; margin: 0 10px; title="PV" src="PV.png" alt="" width="150" height="50"/>
</div>
```

This is what is in my html. I don't know how to get them to css. I have tried the # but nothing will change when I put it in  CSS. What does my CSS need to look like?

Comment: You need to use the `{}` code tool to show your HTML. Please also use the preview window before submitting posts - that way you can ensure it is correct before other people see it.

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't know how to get them to css"? What rules do you wish to apply to them? If you want to style images generally, you can do `#travel_photos img { /* rules here */ }`.

Comment: Looks like your `style` attributes are broken, by the way - no closing quote mark before the `title` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a quote in all of your statements.

```
<div id="travel_photos">
  <img style="display: inline; margin: 0 10px;" title="branson" src="branson.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="75"/>
  <img style="display: inline; margin: 0 10px;" title="cancun" src="cancun.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="75"/>
  <img style="display: inline; margin: 0 10px;" title="denver" src="denver.png" alt="" width="150" height="75"/>
  <img style="display: inline; margin: 0 10px;" title="destin" src="destin.png" alt="" width="150" height="75"/>
  <img style="display: inline; margin: 0 10px;" title="PV" src="PV.png" alt="" width="150" height="50"/>
</div>
```

should work. Notice the addition of the `"` mark after the final semicolon before `title` attribute.